# Regarding whether $f(x)=x^{1/3}+2$ and $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ are polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

1. I read from Barbeau's Polynomial book that - Polynomial is a function of a single variable on it's domain and it must be a finite sum . Now what if I imagine a function like : $f(x)=x^{1/3}+2$ where the domain is $\{x^{1/3}=\text{integer (or any finite value)}\}$. Will this be a polynomial because it will always have finite sum?
2. Suppose a function: $f(x)=x^{1/2}$. Now the fact that this function will produce two answers for a single input, plus it is not always possible to ensure that this function will always have a finite answer, is why it's not a polynomial ... right?

Comment: A polynomial is a function, and it is a finite sum, yes. But we require more than that as well.

Comment: "the fact that this function will produce two answers": no, no and no. A function is a function. $x^{1/2}=\sqrt x$ is a function and has a single value (conventionally taken to be positive).

Comment: I bet that you didn't reproduce the whole definition. Barbeau cannot be that grossly wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Or that's not a definition, just a list of a few properties polynomials are known to have which are useful in the particular context where the quote is taken from. (And then the OP mistook it for a definition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a polynomial is a function and is a finite sum. However, that does not mean that every function which can be written as a finite sum is a polynomial; this is similar to how every multiple of $4$ is even, but not every even number is a multiple of $4$. Here is a proper definition of a polynomial, taken from Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (page $42$):

> A function $f$ is a *polynomial* if there are numbers
> $a_0,\dots,a_n$ such that $$
> f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 \; \text{for all $x$.} $$  (When $f(x)$ is written in this form it is usually tacitly
> assumed that $a_n\neq0$.)

So $\phi(x)=x^{1/3}+2$ is not a polynomial because the powers of $x$ must be nonnegative integers. However, $\alpha(x)=5x^6+137x^4-\pi$, $\beta(x)=x^2$, and $\gamma(x)=1$ are all examples of polynomials.

$f(x)=x^{1/2}$ is not a polynomial for the same reason as before. However, this function does not produce two outputs. By definition, a function must have only one output. So even though the equation $x^2=4$ has two solutions, $4^{1/2}=\sqrt{4}=2$. In general, $a^{1/2}=\sqrt{a}$ denotes the nonnegative number $x$ such that $x^2=a$. So $\sqrt{4}=2$, $\sqrt{0}=0$, etc.

Also, $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ always produces finite answers. The square root of a nonnegative real number is also a nonnegative real number (and all real numbers are finite).

Comment: Is there any reason behind why n has to be a positive integer? Plus your answer is the most helpful .Thank you.

Comment: @Tekton_infernus: I'm glad I could help. The fact that $n$ has to be positive (or zero) is just a matter of convention: a polynomial is defined that way. There are a number of reasons that we make this definition. Collectively, polynomials have many properties in common, e.g. every non-constant polynomial has at least one real root. If $f(x)=x^{-1}$ was considered a polynomial, then we would have to give up this theorem.

Comment: @Tekton_infernus: So it is more convenient to define a polynomial this way. It's for the same reason that an infinite series like $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots$ is also not a polynomial—infinite series have fundamentally different properties to finite sums.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Comment: Interestingly, Barbeau also includes the functions that can be rewritten as sums of monomials in their domain. This is very rarely done. (I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: So does he consider $f(x)=x$, with $x>0$, to be a polynomial?

Comment: @Joe: absolutely, see the given examples. Spivak is somewhat elusive by saying "for all $x$".

Comment: @YvesDaoust: What a bizarre convention! The function $f$ I have just defined, despite being a polynomial of degree $1$ according to the author's definition, does not have any roots. But I'm glad your answer clarifies what the author intended, even though that intention is a little odd.

Comment: @Joe sorry if it sounds silly but I didn't understand .Did you mean it's bizarre for f(x)=x to have a root?

Comment: @Joe: same goes with Spivak. "For all $x$" does not necessarily mean "For all $x$ in the complex plane".

Comment: @Tekton_infernus: Barbeau allows the domain of a polynomial to be something other than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. For example, he considers $f(x)=x$, with $x>0$, to be a polynomial. It seems odd to call $f$ a polynomial when it doesn't have any roots.

Comment: @Tekton_infernus: Does that answer your question, or are you still unsure about anything?

Comment: @Joe So in a nutshell polynomials are kind of functions who show similar interesting characteristics and for that powers are supposed to be non negative integers, But do you know any theorem or anything like that which proves this conjecture(is it called a conjecture ,idk ) Btw Thanks m8 for asking ,really.

Comment: @Tekton_infernus: It's not a precise mathematical statement that "polynomials are functions which show similar interesting characteristics" (even though this is undoubtedly true). So it is not possible to prove this. However, there are *many* things that polynomials have in common: as Yves mentions, "polynomials are the most general expressions that can be generated from addition and multiplication only"; every polynomial with domain of $\Bbb{C}$ of degree $n$ has $n$; every polynomial is analytic etc.

Comment: Some of these properties wouldn't hold if we allowed the domain of a polynomial to be something other than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, or if we allowed the powers to be negative.

Answer (score 8):

Seems that you interpret the original text the way you want. Even though this is an informal section, Barbeau does exclude fractional powers:

[image]

Comment: Polynomials are the most general expressions that can be generated from additions and multiplications only.

Answer (score 2):

No this definition is incorrect and the examples you gave are not polynomials. The elementary definition of a polynomial is a function $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ where $a_r$ is in the real numbers(or complex/any field of your choosing) and $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Is there any reason behind why n has to be a positive integer?

Comment: $n$ being an integer is implicit (because of the sequence $n,n-1,n-2,\cdots0$). But in fact, $n$ is *non-negative*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To start of with as already mentioned in above all answers how is polynomials defined.
I'll try to answer the question of yours that why $n$ has to be a non-negative integer.
So the answer to this is that it's because we've defined it in that way but with accordance to certain reasons. A natural question is to ask what are those reasons well here are two of them :
Firstly , the expressions containing non-negative integers exponents one may face the following problem that is encountering poles, example given
$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{2}{x^2} $$
Now the domain of this function excludes where $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not defined that is $x=0$.
Secondly , when there are terms with variables in the denominator the respective terms becomes rational functions.Again these functions contain the poles where the denominator is not equal to zero making the whole expression undefined.
However , confining ourselves with the exponents as positive integer works properly and serves accordingly.
I hope this was helpful. Thank you !)